# How does the Docker daemon know about the available hardware resources?

Tags: cpu, vmware, docker, redhat-enterprise-linux, core

We are running Docker on a RedHat VM on a VMWare hypervisor. When we added more virtual cores (vCPUs) to the VM the RedHat sees the additional resources and can address it but not the containers running or started by Docker. They can only use **CPU0 to CPU7** and CPU8 to CPU15 are **completely untouchable by any container**. Docker inspect returns no limitation on CPUs. A reboot of the VM did not help to cure this. A cadvisor container also reports only 8 cores available.
Does anybody know how to fix it? Does Docker save the original number of CPUs somewhere? How does the Docker daemon know about the number of cores that are available?

Comment: Have you tried starting a brand new container?  Does that see all the CPUs?  You have restarted the VM right?

Comment: We restarted the VM. We also created new containers. New containers are also restricted to CPU0-CPU7. The VM can use all CPUs.

Comment: That is odd.  I am not sure what would cause that.

Answer (score 0):

We solved it. There is a trick to make docker aware of hotplugged CPUs. We don't know why the old setting survived reboots. The following command was the solution:

`for c in $(compgen -G '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/system.slice/docker-*'); do echo 0-15 > ${c}/cpuset.cpus ; done`